# C: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer

Tags: c, arrays

Im trying to create a function to initialize a board for an othelo game, i thought using generic functions would be better for learning but i encountered problems very early, can someone tell me why is this not working?
I define an othelotype that is a 10x10 int array.

```
othelotype* inicializartablero (othelotype* board)
{
  int x, y;

  for (x = 0; x < 8; x++)
    for (y = 0; y < 8; y++)
       board[x][y] = 2;


  board[4][5] = board[5][4] = 0;
  board[4][4] = board[5][5] = 1;

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `othelotype`?

Comment: it is the following

struct othelotype
{
       int cuadrado [10] [10];

}*board2;

Comment: It is often better to decouple the `struct othelotype { ... };` from the variable definition. Also when you don't need dynamic allocation, you can use `struct othelotype board` and then pass it to your function `inicializartablero (&booard)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue using `othelotype *board` as your parameter, you just have to access the actual array inside it using `board->cuadrado`:

```
othelotype* inicializartablero (othelotype* board)
{
  int x, y;

  for (x = 0; x < 8; x++)
    for (y = 0; y < 8; y++)
       board->cuadrado[x][y] = 2;


  board->cuadrado[4][5] = board->cuadrado[5][4] = 0;
  board->cuadrado[4][4] = board->cuadrado[5][5] = 1;

}
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i meant, the use of cursors is totally new to me.

Answer (score 2):

According to the code in your comment, `othelotype` is not a 10x10 array - it's a struct. Structs can not be accessed using the `[]` operator. What you can do with structs is access their members. In this case I imagine you want to access the `cuadrado` member and then index into that (as that actually is an array).

Comment: So the funcion should receive cuadrado? my idea was to keep modularity or so but im not really familiar with the syntaxis

Comment: You can simply receive `othelotype` and then use it to access `cuadrado`. See my new answer.